# How to show flash message of newly created resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I have a `Product` model and my controller allows the creation of 5 new products all at once. What I do right now is render back  to the same page but what I want to do is also render in the flash which products have been created. So it would say:

`Successfully created: Milk, Soup, Cheese, Bread, Candy`

instead of

`Successfully created Products`

How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
redirect_to :back, notice: "Succesfully created: #{@created_products.map(&:name).join(', ')}"
```

Assuming @created_products is an array of the products you just created and they each have an attribute called name.

Oh and of course you need this in your html:

```
<div class="notice"><%= notice %></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in your controller. You probably have a create action where you actually create these objects, and they problem have a `name` attribute or something, right? So when you create the objects, save them in an array, then use the `map` and `join` methods to put them together. Something like this:

```
def create
    successful = []

    # loop through the parameters
        obj = MyModel.new(...)
        if obj.save
            successful << obj
        end
    # end loop

    flash[:notice] = "Succesfully created: #{successful.map(&:name).join(', ')}"

    redirect_to my_model_path
end
```

Map runs the method you pass in, so `name`, on each of the memebrs of the array and returns an array whose contents are the results of that method: in other words, you get an array of all their names. Join puts them together separated by whatever string you put in. So you'd get something like "Milk, cheese".